# Access to network share folder works in VDI, but not on desktops

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, group-policy, network-share, vdi

I have two separate environments running in our lab computing spaces. We are phasing over to VDI. There are some weird differences going on in each environment, and I believe that the problem is policy based.

When I am in our full OS image environment (Windows 7) we get some access permissions errors on some network folders. When I attempt things in our VDI environment (VMware Horizon View with Unidesk), they are flawless.

We have verified that permissions are correct on these folders. Could their be something causing this problem in my AD policies? I can't think of any other logical problems between the two environments.

I would like to give as much information as possible, but I'm not sure what would be the best information to show.

Comment: access denied errors?  What is the exact error and is it through explorer or what?

Comment: Popup window with "Location is not available" and "is not accessible" and "access is denied"

Comment: Through explorer